# Swift Generic Types and Inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance, viewcontroller

I'm creating an app for iOS and I have a function in a view controller called `MainVC` that has to return another view controller. The view controller that this function has to return inherits from another view controller called `FatherVC`. My problem is `FatherVC` has a generic type, and that causes problems...

```
class MainVC: UIViewController{
    ...

    func returnOtherVC() -> //Here I want to return any class that inherits from FatherVC {
        ...
    }
}

class FatherVC<T : AClass>{
    ...
}

class Child1VC: FatherVC<Class1>{ //Class1 inherits from AClass
    ...
}

class Child2VC: FatherVC<Class2>{ //Class2 inherits from AClass
    ...
}

class Child3VC: FatherVC<Class2>{ //Class3 inherits from AClass
    ...
}
```

I want `returnOtherVC()` to return an instance of `Child1VC` or `Child2VC` or `Child3VC` or other classes like these. How can I pull this off?

Comment: since they are all tied with a generic constraint, you need to have similar constraint tied to `returnOtherVc` without that you can only return one type out of `Father, Child 1, 2, 3 ...`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, see the comments.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController{
    func someInit(){
       //Return any of the children
        let one: Child1VC = returnOtherVC()
        let two: Child2VC = returnOtherVC()
        let three: Child3VC = returnOtherVC()
       //Or the father
        let parent: FatherVC = returnOtherVC()

    }
    func returnOtherVC<FC, AC>() -> FC where FC : FatherVC<AC> {//Here I want to return any class that inherits from FatherVC {
        //Use the required initializer
        return FC()
    }
}
class AClass {}
class FatherVC<T : AClass>{
    //Add a required initilizer so it can be accessed.
    required init(){}
}
//Add inheritance clauses
class Child1VC<Class1>: FatherVC<Class1> where Class1 : AClass{ //Class1 inherits from AClass
}

class Child2VC<Class2>: FatherVC<Class2> where Class2 : AClass{ //Class2 inherits from AClass
}

class Child3VC<Class2>: FatherVC<Class2> where Class2 : AClass{ //Class3 inherits from AClass
}
```